# How to Get List Of Numbers Whose Students Status is Pass or Failed in Single Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I Want To Get Formula Which Give the Output in Comma Separated List Whose Students Status is Pass or Failed in Single Cell in Excel.

[image: For Example Below Out:]

Thank You

Comment: Yes its, Excel-2007 but its not work With TEXTJOIN, i try.. that..

Comment: So, any reference .. bcoz i don't have any idea about that..

Comment: Pointers: You either need helper columns, with helper functions or if you want you can use some `UDF` you can create in VBA.

Comment: Does it has to be in one cell?

Comment: @OverflowStacker yes in one Cell, with comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses a UDF.  First place the following custom function in a regular module (Visual Basic Editor >> Insert >> Module)...

```
Function AConcat(a As Variant, Optional Sep As String = "") As String
' Harlan Grove, Mar 2002

    Dim Y As Variant

    If TypeOf a Is Range Then
        For Each Y In a.Cells
            AConcat = AConcat & Y.Value & Sep
        Next Y
    ElseIf IsArray(a) Then
        For Each Y In a
            AConcat = AConcat & Y & Sep
        Next Y
    Else
        AConcat = AConcat & a & Sep
    End If

    AConcat = Left(AConcat, Len(AConcat) - Len(Sep))

End Function
```

Then try the following worksheet array formulas, which need to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(AConcat(IF($B$2:$B$11="Pass",","&$A$2:$A$11,"")),",","",1)
```

and

```
=SUBSTITUTE(AConcat(IF($B$2:$B$11="Fail",","&$A$2:$A$11,"")),",","",1)
```

Comment: Sorry but i am using Microsoft office 2007 , i am not working in Visual Basic Editor.

Comment: With my solution, you place the VBA code for the custom function in a regular module using the VBE, and then you use the array formulas in your worksheet.  So it's the worksheet formulas that will refer to the custom function and return the desired results.  Or are you saying that you don't want a VBA solution?

Comment: its finally work for me, thank you !! but i need to create custom functions every time for new system ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula solution without Textjoin function and helper column

In `E2`, enter array formula (confirm by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and copied down :

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUM(SMALL((IF($B$2:$B$11=D2,TEXT($A$2:$A$11,"00"),"")=TEXT(ROW($1:$10),"00"))*ROW($1:$10),ROW($1:$10))*100^(10-ROW($1:$10))),REPT(" 00",10))," 00",""),2,99)
```

[image]

And,

If you wanted the result value using comma separator, the array formula become :

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUM(SMALL((IF($B$2:$B$11=D2,TEXT($A$2:$A$11,"00"),"")=TEXT(ROW($1:$10),"00"))*ROW($1:$10),ROW($1:$10))*100^(10-ROW($1:$10))),REPT("\,00",10)),",00",""),2,99)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you done the array entry, confirm by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter 3 keystrokes together. Or you could Google "Excel array formula" for more details

Comment: yes I did using array formula under curly brackets {=...}. but its showing me black cell

Comment: if possible can you provide me your excel file where you did this ?? via wetransfer

Comment: You cannot enter curly bracket directly, curly bracket will be generated after you pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter 3 keystrokes instead of just Enter.

Comment: Done !! Thank You :)

Comment: In the formula bar, try to highlight part of the formula you want to understand and  pressing with F9 for evaluation. Or you can use "Evaluate Formula" built-in function.

Comment: its not working if i have 100 no of student records

Comment: its should we work with any no of roll-no student, but your formula its not work if i am increased the no of student.

Comment: `=MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUM(SMALL((IF($B$2:$B$17=D2,TEXT($A$2:$A$17,"00"),"")=TEXT(ROW($1:$16),"00"))*ROW($1:$16),ROW($1:$16))*100^(16-ROW($1:$16))),REPT(" 00",16))," 00",""),2,99)`  Your formula only working till IF Roll Numbers are 17, if its more than 17 than its not working... So i need Dynamic Solution for this..